# Disable mobile style for vaadin "Select"

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is it possible to disable the mobile style for a vaadin select?

When i open the selection menu on mobile, the items apear at the end of the display.
On desktop the items apear right at the location of the component.
I want the component to always act like it's on desktop.

I tried to find a theme variant for this but the class `SelectVariant` does not offer anything.

Desktop:
[image: desktop]

Mobile:
[image: mobile]

Comment: use a Combobox instead.